# Problema con el mwl-calendar en el titulo de los eventos

Tags: angularjs

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Hola necesito ayuda
Alguien sabe como eliminar esa hora que enmarque al crear un titulo en el mwl-calendar? ya he probado con el 
event{
  tittle: "algún otro titulo"
}

pero el resultado siempre regresa el texto que le de mas esa hora entre paréntesis.

Answer (score 0):

Segun el manual     `vm.events` muestra esa seccion en donde `startsAt`  y `endsAt` son las variables que necesitas cambiar

```
 vm.events= [
      {
        title: 'An event',
        color: calendarConfig.colorTypes.warning,
        startsAt: TuFechaAqui,
        endsAt: TuFechaAqui,
        draggable: true,
        resizable: true,
        actions: actions
      }]
```